# Warning on empty prop: why it happens?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have component, which needs to fetch server data before rendering:

```
class BooksManage extends Component {
  componentWillMount () {
    const { dispatch, fetchManagePage } = this.props
    dispatch(fetchManagePage())
  }
  render () {
    const sections = this.props.books.map((section, index) => {
      return (
        <div className='row' key={index}>
          <BookSectionContainer index={index} />
        </div>
      )
    })
    return (
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-md-8'>
          {sections}
          <BookPaginationContainer paginationClass='books' />
        </div>
        <div className='col-md-3'>
          <div style={{position: 'fixed', width: 'inherit'}}>
            <EmployeesListContainer />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>)
  }
}
```

As you can see, it uses `BookPaginationContainer`, which expects several state parameters:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `currentPage` is marked as required in `Paginate`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

Etc.

Problem: as `BookPaginationContainer` is child of `BooksManage`, what I expect to achieve with `componentWillMount()` is that dispatching an action fetches state parameters which needed.

What actually happens:

```
 action REQUEST_MANAGE_PAGE @ 18:41:49.770
 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `currentPage` is marked as required in `Paginate`, but its value is `undefined`.
 action RECEIVE_MANAGE_PAGE @ 19:01:40.327
```

After all page renders correctly, but I'm concerned with how good is this.

Comment: Where is `Paginate` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't render components that need data until you have that data.

```
render() {
  ...
  if(!this.props.requireData) {
    return <div>Loading</div>;
  }
  return (
    <div className='row'>
    ...
```

Comment: I get the idea, but I'll need some extra callback I suppose, to change 'loading' on actual element?

Comment: You haven't included where / how your component gets data from, so it's hard to say. React components re-render automatically when they get new state or props. So if your fetch dispatch pulls in the required data into state or props, it will automatically re-render with the correct element.

Comment: You could also just mark one element as loading if you want to keep the rest of the layout, such as `{ this.props.data ? <BookPaginationContainer paginationClass='books' /> : <div>Loading</div>}`